# String Interpolation in C#

Tags: c#

```
//Rextester.Program.Main is the entry point for your code. Don't change it.
//Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var type = "Fighter"
            var VType = $"{type}_(192.168.1.90)";

            //Your code goes here
            Console.WriteLine(VType);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying the string interpolation in C# using [online C# compiler](http://rextester.com/). It is giving me an error, `Unexpected character '$'`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most probably you are using an old version of c#/VS

Comment: Well, it says *Don't change it*.  You changed it.  Online compilers are not worth your time, you can get one on your machine that understands this syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The website you linked to supports an outdated version of C# which doesn't support the string interpolation you are using, which was [introduced in C# 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#string-interpolation).